# Как вызвать onError после filter()

Tags: android, kotlin, rxjava, rxjava2, rxandroid

Мой observable генерирует случайное число от 1 до 5. Я фильтрую числа, чтобы они не были равны 4. Какие есть способы вызвать метод onError внутри активити, если значение будет равно 4? Проверять значение и выбрасывать исключение в doOnNext не подойдет.

Мой observable:

```
var observable: Observable<Int> = Observable.create {
    it.onNext(((1..5).random()))
}
```

Мой метод, возвращающий этот observable:

```
fun getBackgroundColorObservable(): Observable<Color> =
    observable
        .delay(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .filter { x -> x != 4 }
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .observeOn(Schedulers.computation())
        .map { code -> generateColor(code) }
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
```

Внутри активити подписываюсь на observable:

```
viewModel.getBackgroundColorObservable().subscribe(
            { next ->
                view.setBackgroundColor(next.code)
                textView.text = next.name
                progressBar.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
            },
            { Log.d("Error", "q") },
            { Log.d("Completed", "q") })
```

Comment: А зачем `Schedulers.computation()`?
Здесь же нет сложных вычислений.

Comment: @Circassian это входило в задание просто

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
observable
            .delay(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .filter { x -> x != 4 }
            .switchIfEmpty(Observable.error(Throwable()))
```

Таким образом, если фильтр срабатывает, дальше по цепочке получаем пустой observable и меняем его на ошибку

Answer (score 0):

Может быть так?

```
observable
    .delay(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    .flatMap { x ->
        if (x != 4) {
            Observable.just(x)
        } else {
            Observable.error<Int>(Throwable("Error"))
        }
    }
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .observeOn(Schedulers.computation())
    .map { code -> Color.valueOf(code) }
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
```

Comment: спасибо, вариант рабочий, но не совсем то, чего ожидал ментор